# Cant't figure out what to do whith this bash script. Keep getting the same error

Tags: bash, syntax

I am sorry if this is very simple, but I am trying to figure out this and cant understand what do I need to do. So, the idea of the exercise is that I need to develop a bash script for replacing substrings in text files. The input data must include the path to the file (relative to the root repository directory), the string to be replaced, and the replacement itself (as a string). The information on each change must be added to the log: src/files.log

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type the file name: "
read file
echo "Which string you will change? "
read str1
echo "What you will write there? "
read str2

if [$#-ne3]; then
    echo "Error"
    exit 1
then
    sed"s/$str1/$str1/g" $file
    size=$(ls -| $file | awk '{print $5}'
    date=$(date"+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
    sha=$(shasum -a 256 %file | awk '{print$1}'
    echo "T02D02/src$file - $size - $date - $sha - sha256">>files.log
else
    echo "This file doesn't exist"
    exit 1
fi
```

#after this I get the error -
edit.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `then' edit.sh: line 12:` then'

Comment: You also need a space after `sed`; there is no command named `"seds/$str1/$str1/g"` (which your string is equivalent to).

Comment: Thank you, I just saw it, but I keep getting the same error after this.

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net/ for automatic analysis before asking for human assistance.

Comment: The second `then` should probably be something else, but it's not clear what exactly. At least you are missing the final `fi` and then probably there should be a new conditional.

Comment: https://ideone.com/PXnx8z has some additional syntax errors fixed. I guessed what to put in the second conditional.

Comment: However, requiring interactive input is an antipattern. Allow the user to specify the target file and the replacement patterns as command-line arguments instead.

Comment: @tripleee I got the whole Idea, on more time thank you

Comment: @triplee requiring input is a good idea if what's being read is something you don't want appearing in `ps` or similar output or in your history file as command-line arguments can.